# Why when releasing a DirectX Texture it fail

Tags: c++, textures, directx, directx9

I have an instance where a class creates a DX9 texture via

```
UINT usage = D3DUSAGE_RENDERTARGET;
HRESULT hr = D3DXCreateTexture (m_D3DDevice, 
                                200, 
                                200, 
                                0, 
                                usage, 
                                D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8, 
                                D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, 
                                &m_texture)
```

Where m_texture is `IDirect3DTexture9*`  and hr = S_OK after creation.

But when I come to cleaning it up in the destructor via

```
if (m_texture != NULL)
{
    hr = m_texture->Release();
}
```

hr = S_FALSE

Why would it fail to release a texture?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Release` does not return an `HRESULT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682317(v=vs.85).aspx), it returns a `ULONG`. That `ULONG` is the new reference count on the object (after the release).

`hr == S_FALSE` in your code because `Release` is returning 1 (which is what `S_FALSE` is defined as), which means there's one pending reference count to the object after you release it (that's not *necessarily* a problem, it could be an internal D3D reference).

The return code from `Release` is intended only for diagnostic purposes. But, tldr, it's not failing, it's working fine.

Comment: Hmm,  HRESULT on other Release() calls returns `S_OK` though.  and when I comment out `m_texture->Release()`, I don't get a memory error when the program is closed.

Comment: Release() *does not* result an HRESULT! Stop casting it to one. It's just returns number, and one you cannot meaningfully rely on. It's perfectly valid for Release() to return 0, 1, 500, 128374, whatever. It simply returns to you the number of outstanding references after release, those references may not have been created by you at all. As long you are pairing every AddRef (or every create) with a Release, you're fine. If you've enabled memory leak tracking in D3D and aren't getting warnings about unreleased objects, you're fine.

Comment: Save yourself a lot of pain and stop using raw pointers to COM interfaces. Use [Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr) so you don't have to worry about manual ``AddRef`` and ``Release`` counts.